# Basic Feasible solution And Optimality condition

Tags: linear-programming

Maximize :

> z = $ x_1 + 2 x_2  -  3 x_3 + 4 x_4 $

subject to

> $ x_1 + x_2  +  2 x_3 +3 x_4 = 12$
>
> $x_2  +  2 x_3 + x_4 = 8$ where  $ x_1 , x_2 , x_3 , x_4 >= 0 $

I have calculated all the possible basic solution 
 these are

1. (0,0,3,2) and z = -1
2. (0,6,0,2) and z = 20
3. (4,0,4,0) and z = -8
4. (4,8,0,0) and z = 20

doubt 1. since in above solution $ x_1 , x_2 , x_3 , x_4 >= 0 $ will we accept solution number 1 and 3 as basic solution for maximization.

2. I have also been asked to show that optimal solution exists **without solving** I don't know how to do that please help

Comment: The constraint set is closed, so you only need to show it is bounded, and non-empty.

Answer (score 2):

1.

All the possible basic solution are: 
$$[0,0,3,2],[0,6,0,2],[4,0,4,0],[4,8,0,0].$$
Values of $z$ are
$$z(0,0,3,2)=-1,\\
z(0,6,0,2)=20,\\
z(4,0,4,0)=-8,\\
z(4,8,0,0)=20.\\
$$
Set of optimal solutions is convex. Then
set of maximum points is segment
$$t[0,6,0,2]+(1-t)[4,8,0,0]=[4-4t,8-2t,0,2t],\quad 0\le t\le1.$$
$$z_{max}=z\left(4-4t,8-2t,0,2t\right)=20,\quad 0\le t\le1.$$

2. From constraints we get
   $$0\le x_1\le 12,\quad0\le x_2\le 12,\quad 0\le x_3\le 6,\quad 0\le x_4\le 8.\quad$$
   Then constraint set is closed and bounded. From Weierstrass  theorem optimal solution exists.

Comment: is the negative basic solution  acceptable

Comment: and can you possibly tell me about this Weierstrass theorem, are you talking about the one we study for essential singularity in complex analysis

Comment: Weierstrass theorem: If a function  is continuous on a closed and bounded set $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ , then  has both a maximum and a minimum on $X$. see  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExtremeValueTheorem.html